# pdfviewer doesnt go to the correct pdf file

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a angular application in 6. And I am using the PDFViewer. I have a icon pdf, where a user can click on and then the user has to go to the correct pdf view. But now when the user clicks on the pdf symbol nothing happens

Googled a lot.

So this is the click function of the Showing pdf file:

```
openPdf(dossierEntryId: number) {
    console.log(dossierEntryId);
    this.router.navigate(['dossier/overig/pdf/', dossierEntryId]);

  }
```

But I see the correct number of the pdf file: dossierEntryId. But the PDf file is not visible. It apprears it can't find the link to the correct pdf file.

But how to solve that?

Thank you

I have this in the app.routes.ts file:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: '/dossier', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dossier', loadChildren: './dossier/dossier.module#DossierModule' },
```

it seems that file is founded, but the Url doesnt fit anymore.

Because If I look in this.router, I see this:

```
locationSubscription: Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
navigated: true
navigationId: 3
```

Ah, yes, I forgot this:

```
{
    path: 'dossier/overig/pdf/:dossierEntryId',
    component: DossierPdfComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
```

Comment: does it change anything converting the id to string? and did you specifiy the route with placeholder in your routing module?

Comment: I did some refactoring . Because I added lazy loading.

Comment: ah, yes, I forgot something. Thank you for your hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved. See my edited post:

```
{
    path: 'dossier/overig/pdf/:dossierEntryId',
    component: DossierPdfComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
```